# Is a quartz job aware of other packages/classes in the application?

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

My quartz job looks like this.

```
public class EmailJob implements Job{
/** */
private DashboardDaoImpl dashboardDAO = new DashboardDaoImpl();  
/** */
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.tapestrysolutions.gwt.predictivelogistics.relevanceengine.server.scheduler.EmailJob");
/** */
private UserDao userDao = new JdbcUserDaoImpl();


public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException      
      {      
        log.info("EmailJob executing");
        EmailNewsSummary email = dashboardDAO.getFilteredArticlesSummary(EmailNewsSummary.cutoffDate());
        EmailNewsBuilder builder = new EmailNewsBuilder(email);
        sendEmailNews(builder.getEmail());
        log.info("email sent");

      } 

/**
 * Sends content to subscribed users
 * @param content
 */
public void sendEmailNews(String content) {
    //sends email
}
```

}

When the scheduler runs the job, nothing happens. When i examine tomcat logs the only thing that gets logged is "EmailJob executing", the very first statement. The first thing inside getFilteredArticlesSummary() is a print statement, so i know it's not executing.

The interesting thing is i can circumvent these methods by replacing builder.getEmail() with a hardcoded email string, and the email gets sent correctly.

This leads me to believe that this job instance (EmailJob) is not aware dashboardDAO and userDao that i initiated as instance variables. These objects access my sql server and return data, they are located in other packages. If this is the case, then how is EmailJob aware of the logger? Is it cause i declared it as static?

Comment: If dashboardDAO  wan't instantiated you'd get a null pointer exception. Could it be that getFilteredArticlesSummary doesn't return any data, perhaps because DashboardDaoImpl  is pointing at the wrong database?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this code works fine locally, it doesn't work in production. This is a GWT project so when running locally it uses the jetty server, in production i'm using Tomcat 7.0.

Comment: Then it sounds more and more like a configuration problem.  Make sure you are pointing at the database you think you'r e pointing at.